# How to convert cv::Mat to torch::Tensor and feed it to libtorch model?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, pytorch, libtorch

I read image with cv2.imread() and trying to feed it to torch model in c++. It has datatype cv::Mat. I think i need to convert it to tensor somehow and then use model.forward(), but i am confused how to do it. Is there some function similar to .Tensor() in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`torch::from_blob`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_basics.html?highlight=from_blob) can be used to create a tensor view over the image data, like this:

```
torch::Tensor to_tensor(cv::Mat img) {
    return torch::from_blob(img.data, { img.rows, img.cols, 3 }, torch::kUInt8);
}
```